# Ngx chips : Get current order after dragging

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-chips

I enabled dragzone attribute  and chips added are now draggable.
So after dragging, how do we get current order of  chips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in Angular you can use [two way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax). In fact you can get the order from the [binded ngmodel](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) value.

Check the examples [code](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/blob/master/demo/home/home.html) from the [demo page](https://angular-mfppay.stackblitz.io/).

Example for Drag and drop inside an input:

```
    <div>
        <h3>Drag and drop</h3>
        <tag-input  [(ngModel)]="dragAndDropExample"
                    [modelAsStrings]="true"
                    [dragZone]="'zone1'"
                    [editable]="true">
        </tag-input>
    </div>
```

Example code for Drag and drop between inputs:

```
    <div>
        <h3>Drag and drop (as string) can be moved to another tag-input (to the next)</h3>
        <tag-input  [(ngModel)]="dragAndDropStrings"
                    [modelAsStrings]="true"
                    [dragZone]="'zone1'"
                    [editable]="true">
        </tag-input>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>Drag and drop (as object) can be moved to another tag-input (to the previous)</h3>
        <tag-input  [(ngModel)]="dragAndDropObjects"
                    [dragZone]="'zone1'"
                    [editable]="true">
        </tag-input>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Worked perfectly. I just looked for an event similar to (onAdd). Did nt think of ng model two way binding

Comment: As a new user, please have a look at stackoverflows voting https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for link. Done with voting!!